# Thread related issue

Tags: android

I am trying my hand on thread with basic example. But facing force close.
Here's the code.

```
   public class ThreadExample extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Thread myThread=null;
        Runnable runnable=new CountDownRunner();
        myThread=new Thread(runnable);

        myThread.start();
    }
    public void Work(){runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


                try{
            EditText ed1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);
                        Date dt = new Date(0);
                        int hours = dt.getHours();
                        int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                        int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
                        String curTime = hours + ":"+minutes + ":"+ seconds;
                        ed1.setText(curTime);
            }catch (Exception e) {

            }
            }
    });
}
class CountDownRunner extends ThreadExample implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Work();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PIyush", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

I checked the DDMS and getting this

```
03-25 00:51:44.145: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
03-25 00:54:59.515: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
03-25 00:55:44.586: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
03-25 00:57:47.935: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
03-25 01:01:22.805: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
03-25 01:02:00.255: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): GC freed 16675 objects / 783752 bytes in 171ms
03-25 01:19:34.195: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
03-25 01:19:35.235: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
03-25 01:20:49.645: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
03-25 01:20:57.285: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
03-25 01:27:24.475: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
03-25 01:28:30.065: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
03-25 01:29:44.835: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
03-25 01:36:45.355: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
03-25 01:38:07.125: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
03-25 01:46:00.256: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): GC freed 16800 objects / 782664 bytes in 205ms
03-25 01:46:58.495: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
03-25 01:50:45.075: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
03-25 01:58:26.595: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
03-25 01:58:43.965: DEBUG/dalvikvm(51): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
```

Comment: My initial thoughts are that it's because you're writing to the gui from your background thread...  Have you tried starting off with an empty Work function?

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace from logcat, particularly the lines starting with ERROR -- lines with DEBUG don't generally give much information about the crash. But yeah, you can't write UI from the background thread; there are just about a bajillion questions here on SO about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working version of your code, which should point you in the right direction for getting your edit control working:

```
public class ThreadExample extends Activity {
    EditText ed1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);

        Thread myThread=null;
        Runnable runnable=new CountDownRunner();
        myThread=new Thread(runnable);

        myThread.start();
    }

    class CountDownRunner implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000); 
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            }// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Work();
        }

        public void Work(){
            try{
                ed1.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() { 
                        Date dt = new Date();
                        int hours = dt.getHours();
                        int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                        int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
                        String curTime = hours + ":"+minutes + ":"+ seconds;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PIyush",
                                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        ed1.setText(curTime);
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("test", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A few things I wasn't sure about:

- Your Countdown runner was extending ThreadExample.  I think this pushes all of your members from ThreadExample out of scope (which is why my version doesn't)
- Your thread doesn't loop, I'm not sure if you can post to the UI, before it's finished being created (which is why there's an extended sleep at the start of my run function).

Comment: Thanks a lot, You do it in a fantastic way and describe it very well. Glad to see your post :).

Answer (score 1):

The line `EditText myText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);` is called before `setContentView()`  so you probably get a null pointer exception, instead, you can do it in this way:

```
public class ThreadExample extends Activity {
EditText myText;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);
    ...
```

Comment: pardon me for using this myText in coding because i never used it in my whole program i delete it but still getting same error.

Comment: I think that it might be the use of Toast in different thread, though I'm not sure regarding that. Can you tell if it runs OK without the Toast line ?

Comment: yah toast is the problem, thanks a lot but still m not able to get my current time into edittext it shows nothing.

Comment: @forsvarir thanks. really liked your explanation. I totally missed the 4th dimension :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed (and should not) to call findViewById or communicate with any view from another thread than the UI thread. The stack trace will say that as well.

Check how an asyncTask works or just use the use the runOnUIThread method.

Comment: i did some modification n work method but still getting some errors or force close.

Comment: I saw the posts above and i guess you've got it to worked now. Otherwise, please add the new stack trace and we'll figure out what's wrong!